# How to properly enable restful-keystone endpoint for model

Tags: keystonejs

Assuming I have a model named "Project", the documentation for restful-keystone suggests it should be as easy as the following to enable an API endpoint for it.

```
exports = module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', routes.views.index);
    app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);

    restful.expose({
        Project: true
    }).start();
};
```

However, when I start keystone I get the following:

```
Rest is not enabled for galleries
Rest is not enabled for projects
Rest is not enabled for users
```

Can anybody explain to me what is going on and how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after some research:

https://github.com/d-pac/restful-keystone/pull/5

This problem only occurs on windows, as the urls use path.join().

Use this https://github.com/d-pac/restful-keystone/pull/5/commits/0d8cf0c1514bad810fbc2345114d913cfb1e921a patch to temporarily fix your problem.

Unfortunately the maintainer has not merged the pull request yet.